# Send variable from one Chef recipe to another in order to trigger a resource block

Tags: ruby, solr, chef-infra, chef-recipe

In one recipe I have a rubyblock that ultimately obtains the port of a service that I'd like to restart.

Individually the recipes work fine and I am now trying to tie the two together.

I cannot seem to pass the variable to the other recipe having tried to follow a custom resource example.

my default recipe that obtains the port is:

```
 Chef::Log.info("Port: #{port}")

 Chef::Resource::Notification.new("stop-solr_#{port}", :run, self)
```

I'm trying to trigger the resource block of the name 'stop-solr_'portNumber'' using the notification sender.

My other recipe looks like the following and has a start/stop service purpose

```
    solrCore = "solr_#{port}"

#define the service - does nothing
service solrCore do
  action :nothing
end

#do something that triggers
execute "start-solr_#{port}" do
  Chef::Log.info('triggers start')
  action :nothing
  notifies :start, run_context.resource_collection.find(:service => "#{solrCore}")
end

execute "stop-solr_#{port}" do
  # some stuff
  # on success...
  Chef::Log.info('triggers restart')
  notifies :stop, run_context.resource_collection.find(:service => "#{solrCore}"), :immediately
  notifies :run, "execute[start-solr_#{port}]"
end
```

My main problem (I think) is that the variable solrCore uses 'port' which I cannot seem to obtain.

Is anyone able to help with what I need ot do in order to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's what `node.run_state` is for. See the documentation here: https://docs.chef.io/recipes.html#node-run-state

Comment: @Tensibai - thankyou, I'll take a look

Answer (score 1):

Variables in Ruby are local by default. You would have to use a global variable to share state between files, either a real Ruby global variable (`$foo`) or using the global `node.run_state` hash we expose to all recipes.

That said: there is a reason that mutable global variables have been a CS cliché for decades. Code like this is very fragile and difficult to debug. I would consider turning both of those recipes into custom resources and calling them from the same recipe with the same input port.

Comment: I'm not a massive fan of globals, at all :) 
I couldn't see how else to do it though and with limited chef knowledge...

The recipe that determines the port is a beast; that in turn collects, sets and builds objects - would this be suitable for a custom resource?

Comment: null, you can absolutely turn it into a custom resource. Basically anything that can be done in a recipe can be a custom resource. The syntax might need to change a bit on specific calls because you'll be in a different context but I'm sure you can figure it out. The main difference is you'll have to provide a property for each variable you wish to be able to pass in, in this case 'port'. You can also call other resources from within a custom resource.

Answer (score 0):

In the first recipe, you can save information in the node.

Sample:

```
node.normal['A']['B']['C']="completed"
node.save
```

and In second Recipe you can retrieve information from the node.

```
status=node.normal['A']['B']['C']
```

and based on the retrieved value you can take action

Comment: Never use node.save in Chef code. Please remove this answer or redact it, it is unsafe.